# PyQt5 QTreeWidget drag and drop with mouse scroll

Tags: python-3.x, scroll, pyqt5

I have two QTreeWdigets full of items. I am able to drag and drop items from one tree widget to another one. But I also want to scroll with mouse wheel through tree items while holding one of the items (while dragging). Is there easy way to do that?

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible, as drag and drop control is "given" to the OS when drag begins: during the operation, the QDrag object starts its own event loop that only reacts to mouse movement and button release relayed from the system. On X11 it *might* be possible by implementing the native event filter (which requires casting xcb events), on Windows you cannot probably do that as drag completely blocks the event loop of the application, and the only possibility could be to do that by using specific platform modules. So, no, there's no easy way to do that.

Comment: Scrolling seems to work but only when you actively moving mouse, probably when dragMoveEvent is fired